# Print sentence tree without using nltk.tree

Tags: python, sentence, parse-tree

I have a sentnece tree like this:

```
[{'ROOT': ['S']}, {'S': ['VPS']}, {'VPS': ['N', 'VP']}, {'N': ['#']}, {'VP': ['PP', 'MV']}, {'PP': ['PREP_EZ', 'N']}, {'PREP_EZ': ['#']}, {'N': ['#']}, {'MV': ['N', 'V']}, {'N': ['#']}, {'V': ['#']}]
```

How I can print its corresponding tree without using nltk.tree? (for some reasons I cannot use the nltk library)

I expect something like this:
[The desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLSWx.png)

Comment: can you provide how would the "corresponding tree" looks like?

Comment: @Manu I have edited my question

Comment: is a visual problem (how to build the image itself) or how to iterate the list

Comment: Just printing something like this in the output is enough. @Manu

Answer (score 0):

Ok let's see if this can help you:

```py
class Node:

    def __init__(self, value, children=[]):
        self.value = value
        self.children = children

    def __str__(self, level=0):
        str = "    " * level + "  |--" + self.value + "\n"
        for child in self.children:
            str += child.__str__(level + 1)
        return str


tree = Node('ROOT', children=[
    Node('S', children=[
        Node('VPS', children=[
            Node('N'),
            Node('VP', children=[
                Node('PP', children=[
                    Node('PREP_EZ')
                ]),
                Node('MV', children=[
                    Node('N'),
                    Node('V')
                ])
            ])
        ])
    ])
])
    
>>> print(tree)
  |--'ROOT'
      |--'S'
          |--'VPS'
              |--'N'
              |--'VP'
                  |--'PP'
                      |--'PREP_EZ'
                  |--'MV'
                      |--'N'
                      |--'V'
```